# Overlap image on map power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using a map visualization on power BI. I want to overlap an image on my map with an opacity of 50% (like in photoshop).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Icon Map? I suggest you download the examples from the [Data Stories Galleries](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Data-Stories-Gallery/Icon-Map-custom-visual-examples/td-p/789914). I'd tell you more but I'm just reviewing this stuff myself :-)